# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,2) (100,100)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I was making neural network model using some of IMDB data. I created bag of words and split data into train_data and test_data. X_train is data to be trained for the model, and T_train is the label for them. I copied and pasted definitions of functions from the book I am studying and defined network model.

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.pardir)

X_train = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in x_train])
T_train = np.array([np.array(ti) for ti in t_train])

network = TwoLayerNet(input_size=max_length, hidden_size=100 , output_size=2)

iters_num = 10000
train_size = X_train.shape[0]
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.1

train_loss_list = []
train_acc_list = []
test_acc_list = []

iter_per_epoch = max(train_size / batch_size, 1)

for i in range(iters_num):
    batch_mask = np.random.choice(train_size, batch_size)
    x_batch = X_train[batch_mask]
    t_batch = T_train[batch_mask]

    #grad = network.numerical_gradient(x_batch, t_batch)
    grad = network.gradient(x_batch, t_batch)

    for key in ('W1', 'b1', 'W2', 'b2'):
        network.params[key] -= learning_rate * grad[key]

    loss = network.loss(x_batch, t_batch)
    train_loss_list.append(loss)

    if i % iter_per_epoch == 0:
        train_acc = network.accuracy(X_train, T_train)
        test_acc = network.accuracy(x_test, t_test)
        train_acc_list.append(train_acc)
        test_acc_list.append(test_acc)
        print(train_acc, test_acc)
```

And I end up with the error below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-cce2ada4f4f7> in <module>
     37     
     38     #grad = network.numerical_gradient(x_batch, t_batch) 
---> 39     grad = network.gradient(x_batch, t_batch)
     40 
     41     

<ipython-input-14-52e9d162e44b> in gradient(self, x, t)
     53     def gradient(self, x, t):
     54         # forward
---> 55         self.loss(x, t)
     56 
     57         # backward

<ipython-input-14-52e9d162e44b> in loss(self, x, t)
     28     def loss(self, x, t):
     29         y = self.predict(x)
---> 30         return self.lastLayer.forward(y, t)
     31 
     32 

<ipython-input-14-52e9d162e44b> in forward(self, x, t)
    146         self.t = t
    147         self.y = softmax(x)
--> 148         self.loss = cross_entropy_error(self.y, self.t)
    149 
    150         return self.loss

<ipython-input-14-52e9d162e44b> in cross_entropy_error(y, t)
    172 
    173     batch_size = y.shape[0]
--> 174     return -np.sum(t * np.log(y + 1e-7)) / batch_size
    175     #return -np.sum(np.dot(np.log(y + 1e-7), t)) / batch_size
    176     #return -np.sum(np.log(y[np.arange(batch_size), t] + 1e-7)) / batch_size

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,2) (100,100)
```

I'm not even sure from where the shape (100, 100) came from..
Glad if someone would help.

Comment: Welcome! A couple of things would be helpful. Are you using pytorch? What is the shape of X_Train, and T_train? Also, a sample of your data would be very helpful...

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently not using pytorch. Both X_train and T_train are numpy arrays and the shape X_train is (1400, 9164) and T_train is (1400, 2). I encoded and padded the data so X_train looks like [[0.59259259 0.44444444 0.55555556 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.2962963  0.03703704 0.59259259 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]...]